# Redirect a subdomain on Elastic Beanstalk don't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, url-rewriting, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I test webapp on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (Tomcat 8).

I would like to rewrite third level domain requests to specific urls.

For example:
  request *aaa.example.com* rewrite to *example.com/#!aaa*
  request *bbb.example.com* rewrite to *example.com/#!bbb*
etc...

This is Elastic Beanstalk /etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aaa.example.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.aaa.mydomain.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/#!aaa$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bbb.example.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.bbb.example.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/#!bbb$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ccc.example.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ccc.example.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/#!ccc$1 [L]

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log

</VirtualHost>
```

But rewrite don't work.
Hope it's clear enough, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Don't you want `[R]` or `[R,L]` instead of just `[L]`?

Comment: Hello Michael, `[R,L]` is possible, but it doesn't still solve the problem that `rewrite` don't work.